# Comparing different data responses from API

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, fetch-api

I am fairly new with JavaScript and the flux of callbacks, so I am wondering how to achieve the next:

```
function getLocation() {
    fetch('https://www.fakeapi.example.com/services/geo-iso.html')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.iso);
        })
        .catch(err =>
            console.error('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch: ' + err.message)
        );
}
```

The `console.log(data.iso);` returns the country ISO reference you are visiting (like MX from Mexico, US from USA, etc).

What I want to achieve is some way to use this function and watch if it comes from US (for example) to do a different thing if it comes from another country, like:

```
if (getLocation() == 'MX') {
   console.log('Do this');
} else if (getLocation() == 'US') {
   console.log('Do that');
}
```

I tried putting a callback to another function that analyzes the ISO code, but it does not convince me at all.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch returns a Promise that you can then continue the chain.

```js
const location = getLocation(); // returns a promise
location.then((data) => {
    switch (data.iso) {
       case 'MX':
          // Do something for Mexico
          break;
       case 'US':
          // Do something for United States
          break;
       default:
          // Do something with any other ISO
    }
});
```